# Formatting Date like moment.js in .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date-formatting

Is there any libraries for .NET that works similar to moment.js but for server-side formatting?

EDIT:
So i can do something like : someDate.FromNow(); and returns things like :
in 2 years, next year, in 3 month, in 2 weeks, in 2 days, in 12 hours, tomorrow, in 30 minutes, in 5 seconds, right now, less than 1 minute ago, 1 minute ago, 1 hour ago, yesterday, 3 days ago, 1 week ago, 1 month ago, 1 month ago, etc.

Comment: .NET has all of this built in. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Comment: I don't see how .NET has built in for example: in 2 years, next year, in 3 month, in 2 weeks, in 2 days, in 12 hours, tomorrow, in 30 minutes, in 5 seconds, right now, less than 1 minute ago, 1 minute ago, 1 hour ago, yesterday, 3 days ago, 1 week ago, 1 month ago, 1 month ago,  etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found the answer: Humanizer take care of this.

https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1):

you can use .Net inbuild functions.

**For parsing:**

[DateTime.Parse Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.100%29.aspx): Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent.

[DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx): Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific format information. The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly.

**For Formatting:**

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

**For DateTime Manipulation:**

Refer:[DateTime Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)

Comment: While there is very useful information in this answer, it doesn't remotely answer the question, and is completely useless in that sense.

Answer (score -1):

We implemented something similar to the old VB6 DateDiff function.

This will give you the difference between two dates based on specific units (years, quarters, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, ticks, etc.).

You can probably use or modify this to give you what you need.  We could probably add an override that takes the units (howToCompare) as a strongly-typed enumeration.

You could use this inside another method that collects the exact time difference in "plain English" to give you something like:  **"The difference between [DateX] and [DateY] is 1 year, 3 months, 12 days, 4 hours, 23 minutes, 55 seconds, and 213 milliseconds."**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Same common parameters as the VB6 DateDiff
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// System.DateTime dt1 = new System.DateTime(1974,12,16);
    /// System.DateTime dt2 = new System.DateTime(1973,12,16);
    /// Console.Write(DateDiff("yyyy", dt1, dt2).ToString()));
    /// Returns:  -1
    /// </example>
    /// <param name="howToCompare">The units to return (m = minutes, s = seconds, t = ticks, mm = milliseconds, yyyy = years, q = quarters, d = days)</param>
    /// <param name="startDate">The starting date to compare</param>
    /// <param name="endDate">The ending date to compare</param>
    /// <returns>The difference in selected units</returns>
    public static double DateDiff(string howToCompare, System.DateTime startDate, System.DateTime endDate)
    {
        double diff = 0;
        try
        {
            System.TimeSpan TS = new System.TimeSpan(startDate.Ticks - endDate.Ticks);
            switch (howToCompare.ToLower())
            {
                case "m":
                    diff = System.Convert.ToDouble(TS.TotalMinutes);
                    break;
                case "s":
                    diff = System.Convert.ToDouble(TS.TotalSeconds);
                    break;
                case "t":
                    diff = System.Convert.ToDouble(TS.Ticks);
                    break;
                case "mm":
                    diff = System.Convert.ToDouble(TS.TotalMilliseconds);
                    break;
                case "yyyy":
                    diff = System.Convert.ToDouble(TS.TotalDays / 365);
                    break;
                case "q":
                    diff = System.Convert.ToDouble((TS.TotalDays / 365) / 4);
                    break;
                default:
                    //d
                    diff = System.Convert.ToDouble(TS.TotalDays);
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            diff = -1;
        }

        return diff;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look to [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/), noda time is a .net library for really advanced datetime manipulation.

Comment: Noda Time does not have the feature requested.  This should not be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

.NET class library have lots of date and time formatting features: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx